# If I'm asked to prove that $n \le m$, is it sufficient to show that $n < m$?

Tags: inequality, induction

I have a homework question, which is to prove by induction that

$\sum\limits_{r=1}^{n} \frac{1}{\sqrt{r}} \leq 2\sqrt{n}$ for every integer $n \geq 1$.

I've managed to show by induction that

$\sum\limits_{r=1}^{k+1} \frac{1}{\sqrt{r}} \leq 2\sqrt{k} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}$

and since $2\sqrt{k} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{k}} \lt 2\sqrt{k+1}$,

$\sum\limits_{r=1}^{k+1} \frac{1}{\sqrt{r}} \lt 2\sqrt{k+1}$, given that the conjecture is true for $n = k$.

But is this enough to prove the original statement, since I only attempted to show that the sum is strictly smaller than the right-hand side? I feel like there's a nicer way to prove this.

Comment: on the second and third summations, you've omitted $1/\sqrt{r}$. Am I missing something or is this a typo?

Comment: Yes, it is... See that you are missing the summation terms in your sums.

Comment: It was a typo, fixed now.

Comment: Which grade are you in, Jake?

Comment: I'm in first year at university.

Answer (score 5):

Yes! If you have proved $n<m$, then you have proved both $n\leq m$ and $n\neq m$.

Comment: If you have proved $n<m$ you have not proved that $n\neq m$.

Comment: @Martingalo: Are you claiming two natural numbers which are strictly smaller than each other might still be equal?

Comment: @Martingalo show me a case where $n<m$ and $n=m$

Comment: And who downvoted this? It's a perfectly good answer.

Comment: I mean, for me $3<4$ and $3\leq 4$ but also $4\leq 4$. So, $3<4$ implies also $3\leq 4$ but $4\leq 4$ does not imply $4\neq 4$. Am I being confused? :)

Comment: @Martingalo: Yes. In your example, $n=3$ and $m=4$. As you noticed correctly, $n<m$ and that implies $n\le m$. But it also implies $n\not=m$, i.e. $3\not=4$. You are right in that it does *not* imply $m\not=m$ ($4\not=4$) and there is also no reason it should.

Comment: mm.. I see, I think it's a picky question, cause many times we may write $<$ when we mean $\leq$ and hence I was confused that $<$ and $\leq$ are essentially the same. But $<$ does not imply $\neq$. Anyways, thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @Martingalo: $n<m\rightarrow n\neq m$

Comment: Imagine I start from $A$ and I apply successive inequalities which I, a priori, think are strict. Then suddenly I find out that $A<B<C<...<A$, then this does not imply $A\neq A$, thats why I got confused :) sorry

Comment: Yes, it does imply $A\neq A$, since "$<$" is a transitive relation.

Comment: @Martingalo: This is why in math we don't use things that we think, we use things that we know. :)

Answer (score 1):

$ n \leq m$ is a **disjunction:** shorthand for $$n \lt m \;\text{ OR }\; n = m$$

Hence, to prove $n \leq m,\;$ it suffices to prove either $\;n\lt m$ or $\;n = m$. Note that the disjuncts need NOT both be true in order for $n\leq m$ to be true. In fact, this disjuntion is an exclusive or: the disjuncts *cannot* both be true.